# Next.js How to fix ERR_PNPM_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE?

Tags: npm, next.js, vercel, pnpm

When I deploy my project to Vercel, the build fails with this error:

```
ERR_PNPM_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE  Cannot install with "frozen-lockfile" because pnpm-lock.yaml is not up-to-date with package.json
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by the PNPM package manager that Vercel uses if it's out of sync with NPM.

It happens when you are using both NPM and PNPM on your Next.js project.

Learn more about PNPM here: https://pnpm.io/

To fix this issue, sync npm and pnpm by running `pnpm install` and pushing the updated `pnpm-lock.yaml` file. You can also choose to remove your `package-lock.json` file if you want to completely switch to pnpm (it works mostly the same as `npm` with a few benefits (mainly no large node_modules folder)

Answer (score 1):

Delete pnpm-lock.yaml file and push it into Github for Vercel to redeploy